# Angular App breaking in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, cross-browser, angular-ui-router

**Edit**: *This problem is fixed. I found that there was a problem using "watch" as a name for one of my states in ui-router because of this issue in Firefox* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch.

*Scroll to the bottom of this question to see the final edits in the main.js file.*

So I created an **Angular app (version 1.5.7)** You can checkout the project files and a link to the live deployment here -> https://github.com/StephenGrable1/AngularJS-Single-Page

It works perfectly in Chrome and in Safari. However, in Firefox I receive an error $injector:modulerr.

The error in the console provides a link to a part of the Angular Documentation which reads: "Failed to instantiate module Single-Page-App due to:
queued.shift is not a function". I have injected my dependencies for good practice but that still doesn't fix the issue in Firefox.

Below are my two main Angular files.

### This is my controllers/contactCtrl.js

```
angular
.module('Single-Page-App')
.controller('contactCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.contact = {name : '', email : '', subject : '', message : ''};

var app = angular.module('Single-Page-App', ['ui.router', 'ngMessages']);

...
```

### and this is my js/main.js which uses ui-router

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
$stateProvider
.state("home", {
    url:"/home",
    views: {
        "main@": {
            templateUrl: "partials/home.html"
        }
    }
})
.state("listen", {
    url:"/listen",
    views: {
        "main@": {
            templateUrl: "partials/listen.html"
        }
    }
})
.state("watch", {
    url:"/watch",
    views: {
        "main@": {
            templateUrl: "partials/watch.html"
        }
    }
})
.state("contact", {
    url:"/contact",
    views: {
        "main@": {
            templateUrl: "partials/contact.html"
        }
    }
}
}])
```

I want to be a good programer and be concerned about *cross-browser functionality* (I know impressive right) so I want to find out how to solve this issue for myself and anyone else who might also run into this problem.

**UPDATE**: This is the order of my scripts at the bottom of my index.html

```
<script src="js/angular-1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-1.5.7/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-1.5.7/angular-messages.js"></script>

<!-- Our Custom Javascripts -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/contactCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/footer.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And I revised the controller to use the var "app" like so:

```
app.controller('contactCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
        $scope.contact = {name : '', email : '', subject : '', message : ''};
```

However the error still exists in Firefox :/

**UPDATE**:
When I remove the name in ng-app the application appears in the Firefox browser fine, but the routes don't work and the angular controllers don't either. Below is the code that solves the Firefox bug but breaks the angular functionality.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app> <!-- When I rename to np-app="Single-Page-App" it breaks in Firefox. -->
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>AngularJS Single Page</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div ng-include="'templates/header.html'"></div>
   <div ui-view="main"></div><!-- This is where the website content gets inserted -->
   <div ng-include="'templates/footer.html'"></div>

    <script src="js/angular-1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-1.5.7/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-1.5.7/angular-messages.js"></script>

    <!-- Our Custom Javascripts -->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/contactCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/footer.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


   </body>
</html>
```

Update:

## **Problem Fixed!!!**

So apparently the "watch" name for one of my states was causing bugs so I switched it to "watchHere" and it works in Firefox! This name change fixes the bug! In the future, I hope this saves some poor wandering soul some time.

```
   var app = angular.module('Single-Page-App', ['ui.router', 'ngMessages']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    var home = {
        name: 'home',
        url: '/home',
        views: {
                "main@": {
                    templateUrl: "partials/home.html"
                }
            }
      }

      var listen = {
        name: 'listen',
        url: '/listen',
        views: {
                "main@": {
                    templateUrl: "partials/listen.html"
                }
            }
      }

        var contact = {
        name: 'contact',
        url: '/contact',
        views: {
                "main@": {
                    templateUrl: "partials/contact.html"
                }
            }
      }

        var watchHere = {
        name: 'watchHere',
        url: '/watch',
        views: {
                "main@": {
                    templateUrl: "partials/watch.html"
                }
            }
      }

      $stateProvider.state(home);
      $stateProvider.state(listen);
      $stateProvider.state(contact);
      $stateProvider.state(watchHere);



}])

angular.bootstrap(document, ['Single-Page-App']);
```

Answer (score 0):

modify order code

MAIN.js

```
 // first LINE
    var app = angular.module('Single-Page-App', ['ui.router', 'ngMessages']);
    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
$stateProvider
.state("home", {
    url:"/home",
    views: {
        "main@": {
            templateUrl: "partials/home.html"
        }
    }
})
.state("listen", {
    url:"/listen",
    views: {
        "main@": {
            templateUrl: "partials/listen.html"
        }
    }
})
.state("watch", {
    url:"/watch",
    views: {
        "main@": {
            templateUrl: "partials/watch.html"
        }
    }
})
.state("contact", {
    url:"/contact",
    views: {
        "main@": {
            templateUrl: "partials/contact.html"
        }
    }
}
}])
```

var "app" is you Module

file CONTROLLER.JS

```
app.controller('contactCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.contact = {name : '', email : '', subject : '', message : ''};
```

and order files

```
1. <script src="angular.min.js">
2. <script src="main.js">
3. <script src="controller.js">
```

and use this structure in MAIN:

```
    app.config(['$stateProvider',function($stateProvider ) {

        var home = {
        name: 'home',
        url: '/home',
        views: {
                "main@": {
                    templateUrl: "partials/home.html"
                }
            }
      }

      var contact = {
        name: 'contact',
        url: '/contact',
        views: {
                "main@": {
                    templateUrl: "partials/watch.html"
                }
            }
      }

var example = {
    name: 'example',
    url: '/example',
    views: {
      "main@": {
        templateUrl: "partials/home.html"
      }
    }
  }

var example2 = {
    name: 'example2',
    url: '/example2',
    views: {
      "main@": {
        templateUrl: "partials/home.html"
      }
    }
  }

      $stateProvider.state(home);
      $stateProvider.state(contact);
      $stateProvider.state(example);
      $stateProvider.state(example2);

    }])
```

Comment: Thanks Alfredo, I have updated the files in my controller, but my index.html already contained the order of script files you suggested and the error still appears in Firefox

Comment: Hey Alfredo, I really appreciate all the help, the changes you suggested are nice ways to clean up the code, but unfortunately the problem still exists in Firefox after the suggested edits.

Comment: I verify in firefox. I going to do pull request un github.

Comment: Weird, so I tried your solution and it works fine with two routes... but as soon as I add a third route the application breaks again...